# Clickhouse extend storage for the existing table

Tags: clickhouse

I have one ClickHouse table and my disk space shows me 1 GB left, I added one more disk, mounted it in ClickHouse and I can see it in system.disks.

How can I extend the current table storage so new data for my table will be written to the new mounted disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have following options here

1. add a new disk to `default` storage policy with proper move factor
2. create a new storage policy with proper move factor and change storage policy via `ALTER TABLE db.table MODIFY SETTINGS storage_policy='new_policy`

look details in documentation
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree#table_engine-mergetree-multiple-volumes_configure